# C# implementation of LRU-cache

Tags: c#, algorithm, cache

I implemented a LRU-cache in C# and wanted to hear suggestions in making it more readable and maybe even more compact.

```
public class LRUCache<K, V>
{
    public int Capacity { get; }
    Dictionary<K, V> cache;
    K[] keyRingBuffer;
    int ringBufferIndex;

    int LRUIndex => (ringBufferIndex + 1) % Capacity;
    K LRU => keyRingBuffer[LRUIndex];

    public LRUCache(int capacity)
    {
        Capacity = capacity;
        cache = new Dictionary<K, V>(Capacity);
        keyRingBuffer = new K[Capacity];
        ringBufferIndex = 0;
    }

    public bool Contains(K key) => cache.ContainsKey(key);
    public int Size => cache.Count;

    public V Get(K key)
    {
        if (cache.TryGetValue(key, out var value))
        {
            keyRingBuffer[LRUIndex] = key;
            ringBufferIndex = LRUIndex;
            return value;
        }
        throw new Exception($"Element for key {key} not in cache");
    }

    public void Add(K key, V val)
    {
        if (cache.Count >= Capacity) cache.Remove(LRU);

        ringBufferIndex = LRUIndex;
        keyRingBuffer[ringBufferIndex] = key;
        cache.Add(key, val);
    }
}
```

I would love it to be more like -- how Robert Martin says -- "well written prose".

Comment: Looks like you are evicting the “most” recently used element, not least recently used.

Answer (score 1):

First make it right. Then worry about readability, compactness, etc.

Consider the following use case:

```
var foos = new LRUCache<Foo, Bar>(2);
foos.Add(foo1, bar1);
foos.Add(foo2, bar2);
Quux(foos.Get(foo1));
Quux(foos.Get(foo1));
// The least recently used key is foo2, so it should be evicted
foos.Add(foo3, bar3);
Assert(foos.Contains(foo1));
```

Why does it fail?